# How to add qty if the name is duplicate in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel application, and my database contains product name and qty. How do I show just one product name when many of the same product names have a different qty, and the qty is the sum? Is there any function that I can use in this case?

For example...

| Product Name | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| AC ASUS ZA550KL - Zenfone Live L1 | 2 |
| AC ASUS ZA550KL - Zenfone Live L1 | 10 |
| AC ASUS ZA550KL - Zenfone Live L1 | 1 |
| BM XIAOMI Redmi Note 7- 7 Pro | 20 |
| BM XIAOMI Redmi Note 7- 7 Pro | 1 |

I want the result like this:

| Product Name | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| AC ASUS ZA550KL - Zenfone Live L1 | 13 |
| BM XIAOMI Redmi Note 7- 7 Pro | 21 |

Answer (score 1):

first use `groupBy` and use `sum` in `selectRaw`:

```
Product::groupBy('product_name')->selectRaw('sum(qty) as qty')->get()
```